# How to revert / convert grayscale image to RGB image in PHP or Python

Tags: python, php

I have successfully converted an Image to Grayscale, I want to revert the Grayscale Image to RGB Image. Please help. Thanks in advance.
This my code to convert an image to grayscale

```
$gdlogo = imagecreatetruecolor($width_logo, $heigth_logo);
for((int) $start_x=0;$start_x<$width_logo;$start_x++){
    for((int) $start_y=0;$start_y<$heigth_logo;$start_y++){      
        $color_index = imagecolorat($imglogo, $start_x, $start_y);
        $color_tran = imagecolorsforindex($imglogo, $color_index);
        $red = $color_tran["red"];
        $green = $color_tran["green"];
        $blue = $color_tran["blue"];
        $image_get[$start_x][$start_y] =$red.$green.$blue;
        $colors= (0.299*$red) + (0.587*$green) + (0.114*$blue);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($gdlogo,$colors[0],$colors[1],$colors[2]); 
        imagesetpixel($gdlogo,$start_x,$start_y, $color);
    }
}
```

there I saw a way to change the gray image by multiplying the color index: (0.299 * $ red) + (0.587 * $ green) + (0.114 * $ blue); so it turns gray
I think if the color index is divided by (0.299 / $ red) + (0.587 / $ green) + (0.114 / $ blue); it will return to RGB, but it doesn't work

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: maybe python can revert grayscale to rgb image to?

Comment: I am pretty sure it can

Comment: How to? I can run python on PHP

Comment: Just a kind reminder that SO is not a code producing service. You should try things on your own first and come back when you are stuck. Yes you could do this using python and you will find plenty of good ressources online. Good luck

Comment: Yes, thank you, I tried using PHP and I can't find a way and I don't really understand using Python

Answer (score 0):

The color should be before the divisor.

**So instead:**

```
($ red/0.299)+($ green/0.587)+($ blue/0.114)
```